# Permalink structure shows question mark

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

I have made a site with a front controller in PHP, but I have some problems with the URL and permalinks. When I call a page to show a list of buildings (I use the word `byggnader` which is swedish for `buildings`) , I don't get a clean permalink like this:

```
/byggnader/
```

Despite settings in the .htaccess file I get a permalink like this:

```
/byggnader/?p=byggnader
```

When I select a building a new page is created and then I get a correct permalink like this:

```
/byggnader/name
```

But why doesn't it work with this in the first step:

```
/byggnader/
```

I don't want this to be visible:

```
?p=byggnader
```

That should not be visible! Just:

```
/byggnader/
```

This is part of my .htaccess file:

```
# List of all buildings
RewriteRule ^byggnader$ /?p=byggnader [L,QSA]

# The selected building to open a new page
RewriteRule ^byggnader/(.+)$ /?p=byggnad&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And this is part of my front controller:

```
$page = isset($_GET["p"]) ? $_GET["p"] : "start";

switch($page) {

case 'byggnader':   require_once('buildings.php'); break; // All buildings
case 'byggnad':     require_once('building.php'); break; // One building

}
```

It all worked fine when I developed the site on localhost, but when I uploaded the code to the host, I got this problem. Help is preciated!

Comment: What link do you use in your HTML?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm using this:<a href="/byggnader">Byggnader</a>

Comment: Does anyone has a clue?